# "Semiclassical approximation" in random matrix theory

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, random-matrices, quantum-mechanics

I am reading [Planar Diagrams](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103901558) by Brezin, Parisi, Itzykson and Zuber.  If you specialize the discussion in section 5 there we seem to derive the eigenvalue distribution of $N \times N$ random Hermitian matrices.

$$ N = \sum_k \theta(e_F - e_k) \approx \int \frac{d\lambda \, dp}{2\pi} \theta\bigg(e_F - \tfrac{1}{2}(p^2 + \lambda^2)\bigg) = \int \frac{d\lambda }{2\pi} \sqrt{2 e_F - \lambda^2 }\;\theta(2e_F - \lambda^2)$$

Here $\theta(x) = \mathbf{1}_{x \geq 0}$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).  Assuming this "semiclassical approximation" in the second equality, it looks like we have a very simple proof of the [Wigner Semicircle Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_semicircle_distribution) just by setting Here I have set the constant $g = 0$ and $e_F$ is the "[Fermi energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy)" (possibly zero).

The paper goes on to say the "large N vaccum diagrams" are equivalent to the ground state eigenvalues of the Laplacian $\Delta$ on the space of Hermitian matrices, under the [Hilbert-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) norm.

$$ H = -\tfrac{1}{2}\Delta + V = \bigg( \sum_k \tfrac{\partial^2}{\partial M_{kk}^2} + \sum_{i < j} \tfrac{\partial^2}{\partial M_{ij}^2} + \tfrac{\partial^2}{\partial \overline{M}_{ij}^2} 
\bigg) + \tfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}M^2$$

This short proof seems a little too good to be true.  What parts of that discussion are not rigorous? What is the mathematical counterpart of this semiclassical approximation and how is it justifified?